# SQL80001: Incorrect Syntax:" Create Procedure" must be the only statement in the batch

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

When I try to create a procedure, I get an error message:

> SQL80001: Incorrect Syntax:" Create Procedure" must be the only statement in the batch

This is my procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_UserRoles_Select]
(
    @Rolename VARCHAR(30) = ''
)
AS
BEGIN
    Select ID,Name
    FROM
        AspNetRoles
    WHERE
        Name like  @Rolename +'%'
END
```

What does the error mean and how to fix it?

Answer (score 7):

You just need to put a `GO` batch separator around your `CREATE PROCEDURE`. You have something else above it, and it needs to be in its own batch. Hence the `GO` that's needed.

```
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_UserRoles_Select]
(
    @Rolename VARCHAR(30) = ''
)
AS
BEGIN
    Select ID,Name
    FROM
        AspNetRoles
    WHERE
        Name like  @Rolename +'%'
END
GO
```

A `GO` is also needed after the script if there is code following the `END`. The `BEGIN` and `END` statements are superfluous so all code in the batch will be part of the stored procedure.